# Quickest way to determine if a remote PC is online

Tags: vba, ping, filesystemobject

I tend to run a lot of commands against remote PCs, but I always check to make sure they are online first. I currently use this code:

```
If objFSO.FolderExists("\\" & strHost & "\c$") Then
    'The PC is online so do your thing
```

However, when the remote PC is not online, it takes my laptop ~45 seconds before it times out and resolves to `FALSE`.

Is there a way to hasten the timeout? Or is there another easily implementable solution to determine if a PC is online?

Comment: I thought about implement ping in VBA, but...I'm lazy :) . I never thought of creating a WScript object and pinging like that though. It works slick (~4 seconds to determine a PC is offline). The WMI method is nice too. It also takes ~4 seconds, and is ultimately the route I will go since I already create WMI objects and thus have the library referenced. Plus, it doesn't pop up dos windows that briefly steal the focus. Both excellent answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `WMI` to ping it.

```
Function IsOnline(strHost As String) As Boolean

    Dim strQuery As String
    strQuery = "select * from Win32_PingStatus where Address = '" & strHost & "'"

    Dim colItems As Object
    Set colItems = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2").ExecQuery(strQuery)

    Dim objItem As Object
    For Each objItem In colItems
        If IsObject(objItem) Then
            If objItem.StatusCode = 0 Then
                IsOnline = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the return code from a ping request:

```
Function HostIsOnline(hostname)
    Set oShell     = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set oShellExec = oShell.Exec("ping -n 1 " & hostname)

    While oShellExec.Status = 0
        WScript.Sleep(100)
    Wend

    HostIsOnline = (oShellExec.ExitCode = 0)
End Function
```

Comment: Just FYI. The question was tagged as [vba] so the `WScript` object won't be available. That means `CreateObject()` instead of `WScript.CreateObject()` and you can't use `WScript.Sleep()`.

Comment: @Bond True. I completely missed that tag. I just based my answer on what I incorrectly assumed was VBScript code. I'll leave it here for posterity's sake.