# Move macro forward when caught/stuck in process

Tags: windows, vba, excel, shell

I have written a macro that uses the `paping.exe` program to cycle through a list of device IP addresses by sending pings and recording their return values. While the macro works as intended for the majority of the time, there are spare moments when the `ping` command appears to be stuck or caught up and stops moving forward.  This causes me to have to manually break the execution and start the process over.

From a more broad perspective, is there a way to handle this `runtime` error.  My thought was to break the list of devices into groupings, and if the program becomes stuck, I could tell the macro to move forward to the next grouping.  While just an idle idea, I wanted to reach out to the community for advice, tips and ideas on ways I could more eloquently handle this issue.  The list of devices that I am pinging is set to grow in time as well.

```vb
Public Sub getPingStatusCode(IPvalue As String, portValue As String)

ret = WshShell.Run("C:\Users\*******\paping.exe " & IPvalue & " -p " & portValue & " -c " & pingCount & " -t " & pingTime, 0, True)  'CHANGEEEEEEE
totalCounter = totalCounter + 1

Select Case ret
    Case 0: strResult = "Connected"
    Case 1: strResult = "Fail"
    Case 11001: strResult = "Buffer too small"
    Case 11002: strResult = "Destination net unreachable"
    Case 11003: strResult = "Destination host unreachable"
    Case 11004: strResult = "Destination protocol unreachable"
    Case 11005: strResult = "Destination port unreachable"
    Case 11006: strResult = "No resources"
    Case 11007: strResult = "Bad option"
    Case 11008: strResult = "Hardware error"
    Case 11009: strResult = "Packet too big"
    Case 11010: strResult = "Request timed out"
    Case 11011: strResult = "Bad request"
    Case 11012: strResult = "Bad route"
    Case 11013: strResult = "TTL expired transit"
    Case 11014: strResult = "TTL expired reassembly"
    Case 11015: strResult = "Parameter problem"
    Case 11016: strResult = "Source quench"
    Case 11017: strResult = "Option too big"
    Case 11018: strResult = "Bad destination"
    Case 11032: strResult = "Negotiating IPSEC"
    Case 11050: strResult = "General failure"
    Case Else: strResult = "Unknown host"
End Select

'if statement on return value for bolding and font color
'and counters
If ret = 0 Then 'CONNECTED

    With pingSheet.Cells(i, 4)
        .Value = strResult
    End With
    totalOn = totalOn + 1
    onOff = 1

    'set the rawDataSheet value to connected status...assumes that the sheet starts with all rawdata values as "connected"
    rawDataSheet.Cells(4, i).Value = strResult

ElseIf ret = 1 Then 'FAILED

    With pingSheet.Cells(i, 4)
        .Value = strResult
        .Font.Color = vbRed
        .Font.bold = True
    End With
    failCounter = failCounter + 1
    onOff = 0

    'give RawData sheet a "down since" date value
    If rawDataSheet.Cells(4, i).Value = "Connected" Then
        rawDataSheet.Cells(4, i).Value = Now
    End If

    ''''''''''''''
    pdfDeviceDump

Else

    With pingSheet.Cells(i, 4)
        .Value = strResult
        .Font.Color = vbRed
        .Font.bold = True
    End With
    failCounter = failCounter + 1
    onOff = 0

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you're not tied to paping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34682073/unable-to-change-ping-timeout-in-excel-vba-ip-list-ping

Comment: I'm not familiar with `paping.exe`, but it looks like the code to do this in WMI would be shorter anyhow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31680992/quickest-way-to-determine-if-a-remote-pc-is-online

Comment: If you're not tied to synchronous processing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29869308/4088852

Comment: @Comintern I love the idea in the link, however, it is a bit advanced given my skills.  If you have a more simplified understanding of asynchronous pings, please let me know.

Comment: @Comintern At a second glance, I notice that the solution is actually yours.  Would love to connect and try to gain a bit more and see if it is a viable solution for what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get `paping.exe` to run on my machine so I wrote some code using `ping.exe` instead.

In principle one can shell out and redirect output to file and then pick up the file later when finished.  We use Windows API calls to wait for a process to finish.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long

Private Const INFINITE = &HFFFF
Private Const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = &H1F0FFF

Sub TestShellAndRedirectPingToFile()

    Dim vIPAddresses As Variant
    vIPAddresses = Array("bbc.co.uk", "wikipedia.org", "cnn.com")

    Dim dicFilesToPickUp As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicFilesToPickUp = ShellAndRedirectPingToFile(vIPAddresses)

    Dim vKeyLoop As Variant
    For Each vKeyLoop In dicFilesToPickUp.Keys
        Dim lPID As Long
        lPID = dicFilesToPickUp.Item(vKeyLoop)

        Dim hProc As Long
        hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0&, lPID)


        Debug.Print "Waiting on " & vKeyLoop & " (" & lPID & ")"
        WaitForSingleObject hProc, INFINITE
        CloseHandle hProc '* be nice and close handles
    Next
    Debug.Print "Done! Files ready to read."


End Sub

Function ShellAndRedirectPingToFile(ByVal vIPAddresses As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim dicFilesToPickUp As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicFilesToPickUp = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim sTempFolder As String
    sTempFolder = Environ$("TEMP")
    If Right$(sTempFolder, 1) <> "\" Then sTempFolder = sTempFolder & "\"

    Dim vAddressLoop As Variant
    For Each vAddressLoop In vIPAddresses
        Dim sTempFile As String
        sTempFile = sTempFolder & vAddressLoop & ".txt"

        Dim sCmd As String
        sCmd = Environ$("comspec") & " /S /C ping.exe " & vAddressLoop & " > " & sTempFile

        Dim lPID As Long
        lPID = VBA.Shell(sCmd)
        dicFilesToPickUp.Add sTempFile, lPID
    Next

    Set ShellAndRedirectPingToFile = dicFilesToPickUp

End Function
```